# WPF Application crashes when closing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Can anyone on here shed some light on this little mystery.
I have a .net 3.5, WPF application that runs on Windows 7 embedded, on a pretty low spec pc (Intel Core 2 Duo, 1gb memory etc). I already have the software running on similar systems with no problem, however when running on a certain machine that I recently installed it on. On occassion, When closing the application down, it crashes with the following details:

```
-Problem Event Name      APPCRASH
-Application Name        *****.exe
-Application Version     2.1.0.0
-Application TimeStamp   52f0a50b
-Fault Module Name       ntdll.dll
-Fault Module Version    6.1.7601.17514
-Fault Module Timestamp  4ce7ba58
-Exception Code          c0000005
-Exception Offset        000343b6
-OS Version              6.1.7601.2.1.0.320.65
-Locale ID               1033
```

I also then have to open the Task Manager so I can close the application fully.

I am able to get the Exception message and a small stack trace as follows:

```
-Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

   -at MS.Win32.PresentationCore.UnsafeNativeMethods.MILUnknown.Release(IntPtr pIUnkown)
   -at MS.Win32.PresentationCore.UnsafeNativeMethods.MILUnknown.ReleaseInterface(IntPtr& ptr)
   -at System.Windows.Media.SafeMILHandle.ReleaseHandle()
   -at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()
   -at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   -at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()
```

I understand that the hardware used is not ideal but I'm stuck with it. Just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Looks like a memory corruption. Could it be that your application did run out of memory and this is a followup error? A memory dump would help to get More Information. What is task manager showing for committed memory user and GDI handles?

Comment: As far as i can tell WPF doesn't use GDI, unless you have WinFormsHost in there somewhere?

Comment: Fonts, cursors, ... are GDI resources. WPF uses GDI+ quite a lot by calling into exported C-style methods in GDIP.dll.

Comment: @Alois: WPF is primarily based on DirectX, not GDI+. Perhaps you are confusing WPF with the Winforms API (which is primarily based on GDI+). See e.g. [Architecture of WPF](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9668c0e1-55dc-466d-8ee0-efac3bcdc5ed/architecture-of-wpf?forum=wpf) (MSDN used to have articles about this too, but for some reason they have been removed from the site, at least for the moment. Cached version here: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:v1MweiOci24J:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441(v%3Dvs.100).aspx)

Comment: Yes WPF mostly uses DirectX and WIC but there are quite some PInvokes defined in PresentationFramework.dll. See SafeNativeMethods.